# How to unrack the front squat?

Tags: squats, wrist

I'm trying to figure out how to properly unrack the front squat. Unfortunately there seems to be a real scarcity for good quality guides on the same. Also an interesting point was mentioned by Thomas Markov in a previous post I made:

> A really high rack front squat and a really low rack front squat are really two different exercises, and you don’t want to be drifting from one to the other over the course of a set.

Can someone explain in a more detailed way what the above means, and maybe emphasize on how to keep the wrist when unracking the front squat?

Comment: You should link to the other question, that would help with context. To me it sound like Thomas is talking about the bar position during the exercise, which has nothing to do with unracking the bar, but it's hard to guess without seeing the original answer.